# Ant can't seem to link to groovy properly in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, groovy, ant

In netBeans 8.2, I'm having an issue reading groovy inside a build.xml file.

I have a project in which I run my script via a build.xml using the build-in Ant 1.9.7.

In it, for my groovy task, I set the following:

```
<property environment="env" />
<path id="groovy.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${env.GROOVY_HOME}/embeddable" />
</path>
<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="groovy.classpath" />
```

For environment variable {env.GROOVY_HOME}, I have set the following in windows environment variable:

GROOVY_HOME with the value C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.10

Yet I'm still having an error ""Script failed" when reaching the step with Groovy at the following stage in the build.xml file:

```
<groovy>
    def corePlatformList = []
    [Groovy code here...]
</groovy>
```

I know the script is working fine as it does run perfectly in Eclipse and IntelliJ.

It would seem ant can't link with Groovy 2.4.10 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have some trivial error.

You need to include the library file.

Change from:

```
<path id="groovy.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${env.GROOVY_HOME}/embeddable" />
</path>
```

To:

```
<path id="groovy.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${env.GROOVY_HOME}/embeddable">
       <include name="**/groovy-all-*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

EDIT: based on OP comments

Here is the complete build.xml and I can see it working.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="runscript" basedir=".">
  <path id="groovy.classpath">
      <fileset dir="d:/softwares/groovy-2.4.5/embeddable">
         <include name="**/groovy-all-*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
  </path>
  <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="groovy.classpath" />
    <target name="runscript" 
          description="compile the source">
        <groovy>
        def corePlatformList = [1,2,3,4]
        println corePlatformList        
    </groovy>
  </target>
  </project>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the ant script? what is happening? how did you test?

Comment: @TheHiddenSoul, please check the edit and I can see it working.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I think the issue is pretty much NetBeans related, like the issue I have with Gradle. My build is working fine via Eclipse or IntelliJ, it even runs fine via the cmd console, but keeps failing via NetBeans.